# C# Unreachable code (Property-dependant array copier )

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, copy, indexoutofrangeexception

I have an array, with number ranging from -100 to 100. Now, I have to make a method that copies the positive ones into an other array.
I made this:

```
static int[] ArrayCopy(int[] t)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int[] g = new int[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
        {
            if (t[i] > 0)
            {

                g[a] = t[i];
                a++;

            }

        }
        return g;

     }
```

The program terminates with IndexOutOfRange, and I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 loops. One to count how many positives there are, and then one to copy them.

```
static int[] ArrayCopy(int[] t)
{
    int numPositives = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < t.length ; i++)
    {
        if(t[i] > 0)numPositives++;
    }

    int[] newArray = new int[numPositives];
    int curPositive = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < t.length ; i++)
    {
        if(t[i] > 0)
        {
             newArray[curPositive] = t[i];
             curPositive++;
        }
    }

    return newArray
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing your array `g` with a size of zero. As soon as the run starts, you try to access `g` at a specific index - which is not present. 
I assume you ment to initialize your array `g` the following way:

```
int[] g = new int[t.Length];
```

Comment: Thanks, it now works, but now the way I wanted. It gives something like this: 0 0 0 0 0 61 23 0 0 12 13.
So it did copy the positive ones, but copied zero to the place of the negatives in the original one. I need an array that conaints only the positive ones. 
Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @user3365304: Perhaps there is *another* problem, but the question you asked *was* answered.

Comment: Maybe consider using an ArrayList, which will expand its size accoding to the lenght of your array. Using an array like you did needs to be set to the correct size when being initialized.